# Django. How to find out a user liked a post or didn't?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have 2 models. Product and Favorite (its kind of like)
Favorite has relationship to product and user.
I need to check in templates do a user have relationship with a product for inserting like or unlike button.

```py
class Favorite(models.Model):
    """User favorite products"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='favorites')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='favorites')


class Product(models.Model):
    """Store product"""
    ...
```

In template I have:
{% for product in products %}
...

I'd think i can do it like that
{% if product in user.favorites.all %}
But i dont know how to get all favorite products instead of favorites

How i can solve it in templates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How I can solve it in templates?

Do **not** solve this in the templates. Templates should implement *rendering logic*, not *business logic*. Django's template language deliberately restricts syntax to prevent people from writing complicated logic in the template.

You can annotate the `QuerySet` with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) to check if the user:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Product.objects.annotate(
    is_favorite=Exists(
        Favorite.objects.filter(user=user, product_id=OuterRef('pk'))
    )
)
```

The `Product`s that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.is_favorite` that is `True` if there exists a `Favorite` for the given *`user`*, and `False` otherwise.

Likely *`user`* is `request.user`.

You might want to make the combination of `product` and `user` unique with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) to prevent a user adding the same product multiple times to `Favorite`:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Favorite(models.Model):
    """User favorite products"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='favorites'
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='favorites'
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'product'], name='favorite_once')
        ]
```

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you, but i have a question. where should I write the queryset annotation?

Comment: In the view that passes the `Product`s to the template.

Comment: And another question. I get those products by expression - category.products. So I have CategoryList as a view that give me a category and in the template I get products from each category. How should I change your code for this case?  
`class CategoryList(ListView):   
    """Return categories and random ad"""    
    model = Category   
    template_name = 'store/catalogue.html'   
    context_object_name = 'categories'   
`

Comment: @Hahan't: where does the `Product`s come in here. Perhaps it is worth asking a new question and share the current view, template, etc.