# Posts which are not liked by user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a Blog App and I am trying to show `posts` which are not liked by `request.user`,

- I have tried using `Exists` method as [Mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61999386/django-how-to-find-out-a-user-liked-a-post-or-didnt) :-

```
from django.db.models import Exists

checkIt = BlogPost.objects.annotate(is_liked=Exists(
                Like.objects.filter(user=request.user)))
```

> But it is showing all the posts.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def unliked_posts(request):

    posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(like__user=request.user).exclude(like__user=request.user)

    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'unliked_posts.html', context)
```

I have tried many time but it didn't worked for me.

I will really appreciate your Help. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a simple [**`exclude(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude):

```
posts = BlogPost.objects.exclude(like__user=request.user)
```